# How to SELECT TOP 100 and then (if i choose it )the following 100 until end of rows - powerbuilder + sql server

Tags: powerbuilder

in powerbuilder app in open event of window that contains dw_1
script contains dw_1.retrieve()
as i have thousands of rows then in dw_1 in sql syntax i added top 100 after select

select top 100 col_name from tab_name
thus i retrieve only 100 rows from table

now i want to put buttons on the window (next-prev) when user clicked it he retrieve next/prev 100 rows (according to rows already retrieved) and when it is last/first  row next/prev is disabled
also when i try to search and pass arg to dw (dw.retrieve(arg)) as pb search in 100 row that already displayed i want when to begin search pb search on all rows (ie clear top 100 in the select stat,) and return only 10 rows that satisfy what i search displaying button (next/prev) to show following rows

any help
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you. Pagination with Oracle statements:

```
select * from (
 select a.*, rownum rnum
 from ( INCLUDE_THE_SELECT_SENTENCE_HERE ) a
 where rownum <= MAX_ROWS )
 where rnum >= MIN_ROWS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Retrieve as Needed property on the datawindow.  From the help file:

> Whether rows will be retrieved only as needed from the database. After the application calls the Retrieve method to get enough rows to fill the visible portion of the DataWindow, additional rows are "needed" when the user scrolls down to view rows that have not been viewed yet.

Comment: in powerbuilder book it says "Retrieve Rows As Needed is overridden if you have specified sorting or have used aggregate functions, such as Avg and Sum, in the DataWindow object. This is because PowerBuilder must retrieve every row before it can sort or perform aggregates.

In a multiuser situation, Retrieve Rows As Needed might lock other people out of the tables." as i have sort and the app is run in a multiuser i do not prefer to use rows as needed